# How do i start to learn Ext Js ? what first i can do?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1, extjs5

I am starting  to learn ExtJS. I had a look through Sencha's website and I went through different blog but still i dont know whats going on. I want to learn ext js from a scratch can anyone link a video tutorial

Comment: Have you searched net?

Comment: Yes sir, i do some code and do what the tutorial say but stil i dont understand whats going on.. what i mean is i  try to do my own work but it always error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified version 4.1 I am including those links:

**API**: 
        http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/

**Examples**
      http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/

**Guides**
   http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide

**Resources**:

1. Sencha Forum
    http://www.sencha.com/forum/
2. StackOverflow
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs

**Getting Started**

1. Scroll through the Examples to get ideas of what you want to build.
2. Read through these Guides :
       ○ Getting Started
       ○ Class System
       ○ MVC
       ○ Layouts
       ○ Components
       ○ Data Package
3. Once you are familiar with these concepts decide which components 
   you will use and take a deeper look at the specific guides under the 
   Components section.  I would also advise reading through the App Architecture tutorials.

**Tools**

- Recommended Firebug Plugin (Illuminations for Developers) 
  http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/

Comment: Thanks Dude i try your recommendation